# htaccess: Redirect links with question mark a the end

Tags: .htaccess

I have a few links that look like this, that unfortunately are being used:

```
http://www.example.com/page/?
http://www.example.com/another-page/??
```

Is it possible to have them redirect without the question mark(s), or strip them out?

I've tried:

```
RewriteRule /page/? http://example.com/page/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule /page/\? http://example.com/page/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/page/\? http://example.com/page/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/page/\?$ http://example.com/page/ [R=301,L]
Redirect 301 /page/? http://example.com/page/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't match against the query string (or even the `?`) in a rewrite rule. Since the query string itself is empty, you can't even match against the variable, `%{QUERY_STRING}`. What you need to do is match against the actual request:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+([^\ \?]+)\?(\ |$)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [L,R=301]
```

It's going to look real weird with a `?` at the end of the rule's target, but that's how you tell mod_rewrite to *remove the query string*.

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't working. Nothing happens at all. There is a lot going on in this htaccess but I do have another completely unrelated `Rewrite` rule just above where I tried this one, that one is doing what it's suppose to. Thanks for trying.

Comment: @deflime if you have other rules, the redirect must be before it. As you can see, [it works perfectly fine for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/viLq3.png).